# How to install flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm very new to programming and I noticed someone mentioned flex box. After reading a lot about it, it seems like something that would prove useful to me. The only problem is that I'm having a lot of trouble installing it, even after searching for about an hour for help. I downloaded it from github, and put this link `rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexbox.min.css" type="text/css" />` in my head tag, but things like `justify-content:center` won't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is a very useful guide to using flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I read that before I downloaded it but it doesn't explain how to get it ... "installed" I guess.

Comment: Sorry, try this link instead: https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Comment: You don't install flexbox; either your browser supports it or it doesn't (and most support it in their own way).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Flexbox is a shorthand of "[Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)", which is a CSS3 module, standardized by the [World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/).

So you don't have to install anything, compliant browsers support it natively.

Comment: Oh... well now I feel dumb haha, but I still don't understand why things related to flexbox just wont work in notepad++ i guess is the best way to describe it.

Comment: @BillJenkins Notepad++ is a text editor, it doesn't render HTML.

Comment: alright another dumb question then, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @BillJenkins I mean that CSS (e.g. flexbox) styles HTML elements. But Notepad++ only edits text. Even if you are editing a HTML document, a text editor will only show you the source, but won't parse nor render it.

Comment: Oh alright that makes sense, but for example I'm trying to center two pieces of text in the middle of a page equal distances from both edges and on another question a person suggested using flexbox and gave me some code to try
But when I try it I get this http://i.imgur.com/GSyhhaM.png

Comment: Can you share the code? Sharing what you have already tried in your questions is immensely helpful in guiding answers in the right direction as well as providing context and clarity on what you're talking about. As per [StackOverflow.com/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. **Include details about what you have tried** and exactly what you are trying to do." Emphasis added.

Comment: @clesiemo3 sorry about that, I kept trying to edit it to get a code box put in but it wasn't working, just gonna use an image of it instead http://i.imgur.com/wRRWS7H.png and http://i.imgur.com/q6dQSty.png is what he gave me.

Comment: @BillJenkins It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gqwnahex/. And see [Comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @Oriol Well now I'm even more confused ... I guess I'll just keep messing with it then, thanks for all the help and thanks for being patient with my tedious questions about stupid things.

Comment: @BillJenkins, As Oriol showed you can use jsfiddle.net to effectively show code in comments while keeping it short. For Questions and Answers though definitely try to include the code itself if not both the code and a jsfiddle link. No shame in asking questions :)

Comment: alright thanks! and @Oriol I can center it at my resolution but if I set it to 1920x1080px or whatever my resolution is wont it not be centered if someone with a different resolution visits the website?